# Can we predict last digit of infinity?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, infinity

We know, $6^n \equiv 6(mod \ 10) \rightarrow [1]$

Let, $M=\lim_{n \to \infty} (6^n)$ then, $M$ is tending to $\infty$ and, from $[1]$ we have $6$ as last digit of $M$ so, have we predicted the last digit of $\infty$ or, there is some flaw in above manipulations?

Comment: The "last digit of infinity" makes no sense because $\infty$ is no number.

Comment: Also $10^n \equiv 0$ mod $10$, so is the last digit also a $0$? The thing is, you have to define the limit and the meaning of "digit" to talk about such stuff. Of course, you can do so, but your way does not seem to make much sense as it gives contradicting results.

Comment: @Peter - Does this mean, I have predicted last digit of a number tending to $\infty$ ?

Comment: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (6^n)$ diverges, hence isn't a number and thus doesn't have a last digit.

Comment: Note also that your reasoning applies to $5^n$ which has last digit always $5$, and $6^n +1$, which has last digit always $7$.  Mostly what you've established is that there are arbitrarily large numbers with last digit equal to $6$ (or anything for that matter)

Comment: What you can say because of $6^n\equiv 6\mod 10$ : Every power of $6$ ends with digit $6$, no matter how large it is.

Comment: But I begin to understand the confusion. A constant sequence (here $6,6,6,\cdots$) in fact has a limit. So the sequence of ending digits of $6^n$ in fact tends to $6$. But an ending digit only makes sense in the case of finite numbers.

Comment: @Peter - Thank You, you helped me come out of the confusion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no mathematical meaning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are implicitly admitting that

$$\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}6^n\right)\bmod10=\lim_{n\to\infty}(6^n\bmod 10)$$

and conclude that both expressions equal $6$. This is the "forbidden step": the first limit doesn't exist and you can't take its modulo.

If you bypass this logics, you can similarly show that the last digit is $0$ or $5$, a perfect contradiction.

---

This paradox arises because you are going to infinity using a sequence only made of numbers that end in $6$ (you could as well have chosen the sequence $10n+6$). But this sequence is lacking many numbers, such as those ending in $7$ (i.e. $10n+7$) also forming sequences that tend to infinity. So the limit below does not exist:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(n\bmod10)$$ and infinity has no last digit.

Answer (score 1):

Infinity is NOT a number!

My teacher showed me a nice way of thinking about infinity in context of limits

> > Let's say, that you are throwing a rock. The limit is a place, where the rock lands. If you throw a rock strong enough, it will go to the outer space and will never land on the ground. It will 'land' in the space, so the space is it's limit. Infinity is like space - it is container, not a point on ground (number)

Also the 'last digit of infinity' (even 'last $N$ digits of infinity') can be any number ;):
$$\forall k \in (0, 10^N -1) \lim 10^n+k = \infty$$